# How to start from center when edit JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing

My table cell center its value because i use a custom rendered like this..

```
public static void setCellsAlignment(JTable table, int alignment) {
    DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    rightRenderer.setVerticalAlignment(alignment);

    TableModel tableModel = table.getModel();

    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < tableModel.getColumnCount(); columnIndex++) {
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
    }
}
```

Use in Table..

```
setCellsAlignment(table, SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

This give me perfect center value of table ..

But problem is when i want to edit a cell, it start from beginning. But i want to edit also from center...

[image]

Comment: Change the editor's alignment - you may need to supply your own editor, maybe have a look at [Using Other Editors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Comment: Can you give me a handful example dear ...

Comment: Mate, the link in my previous comment has plenty of examples - You basic question boils down to "how to align text in a `JTextField`" - if you can answer that, then apply it to a `JTableCellEditor` is easy. I recommend you have a look at the tutorials and try something, if you have issues, feel free to ask a new question, as it stands, you question reads "I can't be bothered to read the tutorials, please someone make it for me", which isn't what SO is for